# Flask app using app factory can't find template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am using an app factory and blueprints to modularize my application. The templates folder is located under the app package and contains the index.html template. However, I get a `TemplateNotFoundError` when viewing the page. Why isn't my template found?

```
project/
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── templates
│       └── index.html
└── run.py
```

`app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, render_template

def create_app():
    app = Flask('__name__')
    app.register_blueprint(home)
    return app

home = Blueprint('home', __name__)

@home.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('home/index.html')
```

`run.py`

```
from app import create_app
app = create_app()
app.run()
```

```
File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 267, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 255, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/FlaskVueApp/dream-team/app/home/views.py", line 12, in homepage
    return render_template('home/index.html', title="Welcome")
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 133, in render_template
    return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 57, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "/Users/saikrishnamohan/Projects/VirtualEnvs/flaskVue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 85, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
TemplateNotFound: home/index.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo: `Flask('__name__')` should not have quotes around `__name__`. 
Fix the typo so that it's `app = Flask(__name__)`.

The argument, `import_name`, passed to `Flask` lets it figure out where directories like the templates folder is. Since the string `'__name__'` doesn't actually describe where your app is, Flask assumes the current working directory. But you're running from the directory *above* your package, so the templates folder can't be found.